# php imagemagic crop resize crop result is image 1x1

Tags: php, imagemagick

Try crop image resize and crop again by this code:

```
$im = new Imagick($file_name);
$result=$im->cropImage($w,$h,$x,$y);
$result=$im->resizeImage($nw, $nh, $resizefilter, 1,true);
$result=$im->cropImage($nw,$nh,$x,$y);
$iw=$im->getImageWidth();
$ih=$im->getImageHeight();
```

But at result have wrong image ($im) size $iw,$ih is 1x1px.

After different combinations found solution, after resizeImage() insert thumbnailImage() with same size:

```
$im = new Imagick($file_name);
$result=$im->cropImage($w,$h,$x,$y);
$result=$im->resizeImage($nw, $nh, $resizefilter, 1,true);
$result=$im->thumbnailImage($nw,$nh);
$result=$im->cropImage($nw,$nh,$x,$y);
$iw=$im->getImageWidth();
$ih=$im->getImageHeight();
```

Why it work? May be other solution is ?

Comment: You would probably repage the image after cropping... http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagepage.php

Comment: Thanks, it work now ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$im = new Imagick($file_name);
$result=$im->cropImage($w,$h,$x,$y);
$result=$im->setImagePage($w,$h,0,0);
$result=$im->resizeImage($nw, $nh, $resizefilter, 1,true);
$result=$im->cropImage($nw,$nh,$x,$y);
$result=$im->setImagePage($nw,$nh,0,0);
$iw=$im->getImageWidth();
$ih=$im->getImageHeight();
```